# Como verificar por javascript se entrou uma nova tag li através de setInterval?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

É possível perguntar através do javascript se existe alguma coisa nova em uma lista `ul` - `li`?

Tipo estou trabalhando com um **refresh** de `serInterval`, porem não esta muito dinâmico, pq? Quando a caixa recebe uma nova mensagem a `Scroll Height` não desce automaticamente..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo acabei de receber uma nova mensagem (**Vermelho** indica onde a scroll esta, **Azul** novo espaço na `Scroll Height`). A lista `ul` - `li` recebe, porem fica onde estava na ultima vez.

Então, há alguma forma de poder sinalizar que recebeu alguma nova `li` (mensagem), para o usuário?

Cada `li` que separa as mensagem são nomeadas com uma classe assim:

```
<li class="colorBox_<?php print $id_m; ?>">...</li> 

// $id_m é o id da mensagem na tabela mysql
```

**CÓDIGO** setInterval:

```
var loop = setInterval;

function setLoop(de, para, nome) {
    var url_ss = $("#url_b").val();
    var url_s = $("#url_s").val();

    clearInterval(loop);
        loop = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url_ss+"/956309372.php",
            data: 'de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#mensChat div._5chat").html(html);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

**CÓDIGO** que chama o setInterval:

```
function openWidChat(de,para,nome) {
    var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url_s +"/chat/chat.php",
        data:'de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success : function(html){
            $("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).html(html);
            $("._5chat").scrollTop($("._5chat")[0].scrollHeight);
    });

    setLoop(de, para, nome);    
}
```

Desde já agradeço. ;)

Comment: Você tem controle sobre o código que insere o li? O ideal seria interceptar o momento da inserção, em vez de ficar verificando com setInterval. Se não tiver controle, será que o seu plugin/API (de chat, ao que parece) não oferece alguma opção de callback ou evento quando algo novo é inserido?

Comment: Se isso fosse feito em Angular, seria superfácil :p

Comment: Então, o código que faz a inserção da li, acredito que basta inserir uma classe por exemplo, unread, no seu setinterval você verifica se algum elemento tem esta classe, se tiver, faz o processo que precisar e remove esta classe.

Answer (score 2):

Há uma pequena biblioteca chamada [insertionQuery](https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery) que detecta a criação de nós usando uma macumba de animação CSS, então não gera peso. A interface não é jQuery, embora seja parecida:

```
insertionQ("li[class^='colorBox_']").every(function (el) {
    $("._5chat").scrollTop(el.scrollHeight);
});
```

Não testei porque não tenho acesso ao código para verificar que os seletores estão corretos, etc., mas o uso da biblioteca é bastante simples, se você baixar a versão minificada (no link, acima) e incluí-la na página.

Answer (score 0):

Use esse evento fora do seu setInterval:

```
$('ul').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
   alert("ul foi modificada");
});
```

Se o seu ajax estiver apenas adicionando as novas mensagens, ou seja, o `li` referente a mensagem, isso vai funcionar. Mas caso o seu ajax atualize todo o conteúdo você terá que adaptar isso de outra forma.

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1upry93h/).

Comment: imaginei isso, verifiquei mas realmente não funcionou por conta que o setInterval ele altera toda a ul, o ideal pegar a ultima classe da li e depois caso uma nova entre ele da uma alerta..

Comment: Deve funcionar se você colocar em um elemento mais acima na hierarquia então. Porém, esse evento faz parte de um [módulo descontinuado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) do DOM, e é possível que seja removido dos navegadores futuramente.

Comment: tentei fazer dessa forma http://i.imgur.com/4v7gsHl.png, mas ele sempre retorna dizendo que esta diferente, mas retorna como **undefined** ;(

Comment: Pensei em uma forma mais simples, porém se esse evento deve ser descontinuado melhor não usa-lo. Tem outras alternativas usando logica de programacao mesmo. Por exemplo deixar uma variavel global que diz quantas 'li' tinha na ul. E depois pelo setinterval vc verifica se existe a mesma quantidade ou se aumentou.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja mais fácil você usar um `setTimeout` lá dentro, pra processar a mudança do scroll após o html ser alterado:

```
function openWidChat(de,para,nome) {
    var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url_s +"/chat/chat.php",
        data:'de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success : function(html){
            $("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).html(html);


            setTimeout(function () {
                $("._5chat").scrollTop($("._5chat")[0].scrollHeight);
            })
    });

    setLoop(de, para, nome);    
}
```

Não vou te explicar o porquê do `setTimeout` "zerado", porque temos essa pergunta com respostas aqui no site:

[Por que as vezes é necessário o setTimeout com valor 0 (zero)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94851/por-que-as-vezes-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-o-settimeout-com-valor-0-zero)