# Por que as vezes é necessário o setTimeout com valor 0 (zero)?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Eu venho observado há algum tempo que alguns tipos de evento só funcionam corretamente quando definimos determinada função que é chamada com o `setTimeout` com valor `0`. Ao contrário, se chamamos essa função sem o `setTimeout`, ocorre efeitos indesejados.

Vou exemplificar com um input que recebe um valor e é transformado para minúsculo.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#teste-1').keydown(function() {
        $(this).val(this.value.toLowerCase());
    })

    $('#teste-2').keydown(function() {
        var that = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(that).val(that.value.toLowerCase());

        }, 0);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="teste-1" />
<input id="teste-2" />
```

Percebam que, quando digitamos um texto em letras maísculas no primeiro `input`, o último caractere sempre continua maiúsculo. Já no segundo caso, com `setTimeout 0`, todos os caracteres são transformados para minúsculos corretamente.

Eu gostaria de saber por que exatamente isso acontece!

Por que o javascript precisa do `setTimeout` para se comportar da maneira esperada - a maneira esperada é a maneira que funciona quando uso `setTimeout`.

Comment: Antes que alguém venha falar na minha orelha: Relacionado em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: Não sei ler tão bem em inglês e a tradução do google chrome fica horrível!

Comment: Excelente pergunta @WallaceMaxters, também queria saber isso. +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Isto é normalmente usado pra que **erros** ou **loops longos** dentro do `callback` não afetem o que vier depois do `setTimeout`, é uma tentativa de **"simular"** os `Multiple threads` ([*multithread*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitarefa)), não é uma `thread` de verdade, mas funciona na mesma linha.

Com o `0` (zero), ele vai se executado no mesmo momento que `setTimeout` é chamado, mas não vai ser necessário o que vem após o `setTimeout` esperar o processo terminar, é como se o callback fosse executado em um "processo" separado

Por exemplo:

```js
function meuCallback() {
    console.log("Level2");
}

console.log("Level1");
setTimeout(meuCallback, 0);
console.log("Level1");
```

No exemplo ele irá entregar algo como:

> Level1
>   Level2
>   Level1

Mas é bom notar que cada motor (tecnologia do browser ECMAScript - popularmente chamado de Javascript) ajusta conforme a necessidade e tenta a sua maneira obter melhor performance, podendo as vezes o mesmo script entregar algo como:

> Level1
>   Level1
>   Level2

Um exemplo que algumas pessoas costumam usar pra evitar erros seria algo como:

```js
function meuCallbackComError() {
    (a + b);
}

console.log("Execução 1: Level1");
setTimeout(meuCallbackComError, 0);
console.log("Execução 2: Level1");
```

Veja que no log aparece algo como:

> Execução 1: Level1
>   Execução 2: Level1
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Ou seja o segundo `console.log` não foi afetado pelo erro.

### Porque não usar o zero no `setTimeout`

Não quer dizer que você não vai usar nunca, por exemplo apenas pra evitar erros que podem ser ocasionados dentro do callback o zero já será suficiente, as situações que devemos evitar o `0` é quando ocorrem processos do próprio browser que podem demorar, como por exemplo renderização de imagens após o `onload`, muitas vezes usamos o `setTimeout` pra esperar que outro processo termine, por exemplo uma imagem inserida por javascript, mesmo usando `Image.onload` ainda sim não renderizou dentro de um milionésimo de segundo (algo imperceptível pro ser humano), então um pequeno "delay" pode ajudar, como:

- `setTimeout(..., 1)` - funciona pra maioria dos casos de renderização isto pode funcionar
- `setTimeout(..., 10)` - este pode ser preferível aos demais e dificilmente um humano irá perceber
- `setTimeout(..., 100)` - em alguns casos necessitamos de um delay maior, aonde existe um elemento que irá demorar de renderizar (dificilmente um humano irá enxergar isto).

### Alternativas ao `setTimeout`

Ele funciona bem na maioria dos casos, mas deve-se notar que scripts que demoram a executar ainda sim irão congelar o webbrowser por algum tempo (variando conforme o script), mesmo usando o `setTimeout`.

Recomendo que leia esta outra resposta, ela explica os callbacks e o `setTimeout`:

- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)

Existem atualmente soluções mais funcionais pra evitar o congelamento, por exemplo:

- [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
- [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

No entanto se queres apenas impedir pequenos delays ou erros que possam ocorrer, então use apenas o `setTimeout`, se quiser executar scripts que levam mais de 500ms pra processar então o [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) ou o [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) podem lhe ser útil.

Note que o [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) está sendo usado por várias bibliotecas, como o [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/exports/amd.js#L1) por exemplo. Veja um trecho do código [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/exports/amd.js#L1):

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

Comment: Guilherme, por incrível que parece, estava tendo problemas num plugin que serve para detectar que todas as imagens dentro de um elemento estão carregadas. Tive que alterar a função internamente para setTimeout com zero, porque o tamanho das imagens não estavam sendo capturados, quando não tinha o setTimeout. Isso tem a ver com o carregamento do browser também?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim exato, neste caso eu geralmente uso `setTimeout(, 10);`, raramente uso com `0` pois podem haver variações de cada navegador (motor)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Foi muito importante. Vou alterar aqui, pois tive impressão que o `0` uma hora falhou :|. E o próprio plugin `imagesLoaded` usa em quase todas as chamadas o `SetTimeOut 0`

Comment: Guilherme, se eu usar esse `AMD`, resolve 100% o problema, ou ainda terei que fazer a pequena gambiarra do `setTimeout 0`

Comment: Então quer dizer que é como o navegador tivesse sua própria lista de tarefas a executar e, que quando usamos o `setTimeout 0`, estamos simplesmente alocando essa tarefa para ser executada por último?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não, ele executa após o delay, como esta `0` a unica diferença é que ele simula o multithread, ou seja não tem como saber qual vai executar primeiro ou terminar primeiro, os Multithreads executam a mesma linha :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters adicionei mais alguns detalhes, voltados a experiencias próprias.

Answer (score 6):

Isto acontece porque você está executando muitas tarefas.

O navegador tem de fazer uma série de coisas, tudo de uma vez e executar o javascript é apenas uma dessas coisas.
Daí se entende que ele deve ser executado de forma síncrona, ou seja, uma coisa de cada vez como se fosse fila e não em paralelo.
Daí a solução é "pausar" a execução do javascript para que a renderização da thread aconteça (`setTimeout 0`).
Embora pareça dizer "executar isto aqui imediatamente" ele realmente dá o navegador a chance de terminar fazendo algumas coisas que não sejam javascript que estão no estado à espera para terminar antes de continuar a executar o JavaScript.

[SOEN - why is settimeoutfn 0 sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Então o acontece no primeiro bloco é algo como o seguinte

1. renderiza o html
2. recebe o input do teclado no html
3. renderiza o html
4. executa o javascript
5. renderiza o html

no segundo bloco ocorre o seguinte:

1. renderiza o html
2. recebe o input do teclado no html
3. interrompe a renderização do html
4. executa o javascript
5. renderiza o html

Answer (score 0):

Por causa da precedência dos processos. O evento keydown chama a api do browser de forma assíncrona, a atribuição de valor chama de forma síncrona.

A atribuição conclui em momento diferente. No caso, primeiro chama o evento keydown depois atribuir. Como o evento concluiu primeiro, o texto não existia ainda no textfield.

Dependendo do performance da sua maquina (creio eu) o resultado pode dar certo.

Modificar para keyup já resolveria o problema.