# AJAX sobrescreve variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não consigo copiar o resultado para a variável `registroJson`, já perdi quase um dia nesse problema:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var registroJson = [];
  var url = 'xpto';  

  $.getJSON(url,function(data){

    registroJson = data; //copiando para variavel registroJson o resutado 'data' 

    // já tentei registroJson.push(data) e tabem não funciona    
  }); 

  console.log(registroJson); //o resultado no console sempre mostra [], array vazio

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax é assincrono e não síncrono, o que roda dentro de (é um callback):

```
  function(data){

    registroJson = data; //copiando para variavel registroJson o resutado 'data' 

    // já tentei registroJson.push(data) e tabem não funciona    
  }
```

Só é disparado depois pois precisa que a requisição termine primeiro, já o `console.log` é disparado antes porque ele está fora do `callback` e não precisa esperar a requisição.

Pra entender o que é assíncrono no javascript leia esta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Apesar de não ser sobre ajax, esta resposta explica o callback:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94853/3635

E o mais importante, pra entender o que é Ajax existe esta pergunta:

- [Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635)

Pro `console.log` funcionar ele também precisa esperar o `callback`, sendo assim faça isto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var registroJson = [];
  var url = 'xpto';  

  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      registroJson = data;
      console.log(registroJson);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Guilherme muito obrigado!!

Com certeza vou ler e estudar esses links que você indicou!!!

Comment: @PauloCesar se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta, se não sabe como fazer leia este link: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635