# estou querendo ajuda no cache.get do redis no node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cache, redis

```
function getCache(key) {
    cache.get(key, (err, value) => {
        if(err){
            return ("err");
        }else{
            return ("" + value);
        }
    });
};

console.log(getCache('fatorial:7'));
```

estou tentando receber o value da key guardada no redis, mas está retornando undefined...

não sei mais o que fazer... desculpem.

O código completo está aqui:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const redis = require("redis");
const fatorialFuncao = require("./fatorial");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.PORT || 6379;

const cache = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json()); 

cache.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Redis is ready");
});

cache.on("error", (e) => {
    console.log("Redis error", e);
});

function getCache(key) {
    cache.get(key, (err, value) => {
        if(err){
            return ("err");
        }else{
            return ("" + value);
        }
    });
};

console.log(getCache('fatorial:7'));

function setCache(key, value) {
    cache.set(key, value, 'EX', 10000, (err, value) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Os parâmetros foram cadastrados no cash com sucesso");
        }
    });
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post("/calculofatorial", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.body.s1;
    let valueId = getCache(`fatorial:${id}`);

    if(valueId){
        res.send(`Obs.: Essa cálculo foi recuperado do cache`);

    }else{
        if(parseInt(parseInt(req.body.s1)) > 0) {
            let calculation = fatorialFuncao(parseInt(req.body.s1))

            setCache(`fatorial:${id}`, calculation);
            res.send(`O fatorial de ${id} é ${calculation}. Obs.: Essa operação não estava armazenada em cache`);

        } else {
            let msgErro = "digite um valor válido"
            res.send(msgErro);
        }
    }
});



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto não faz sentido:

```
console.log(getCache('fatorial:7'));
```

Porque o return dentro de um callback não vai ser SINCRONO, vai ser provavelmente assincrono, e mesmo que não fosse assincrono, ainda sim o retorno está em um ESCOPO diferente da função getCache:

```
function getCache(key) {
    cache.get(key, (err, value) => {
        if(err){
            return ("err");
        }else{
            return ("" + value);
        }
    });
}
```

Não existe return no getCache que você criou, os 2 returns que existem estnão dentro de cache.get e isto não propagará nunca para o escopo de getCache, antes de tudo leia isto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94853/3635

Ou seja console.log sempre vai retornar undefined porque o getCache não retorna nada, para funcionar no minimo você teria que fazer algo como:

```
function getCache(key, success, error) {
    cache.get(key, (err, value) => {
        if(err){
            if (error) error("err");
        }else{
            if (success) success("" + value);
        }
    });
}
```

e executar assim:

```
getCache('fatorial:7', (resposta) => {
    console.log(resposta);
});
```

Se quiser pegar o erro:

```
getCache('fatorial:7', (resposta) => {
    console.log(resposta);
}, (error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Mas se me recordo em `Express`, assim como na maioria, não vai reconhecer o assíncrono dentro da rota para usar o `res.send` e não posso afirmar com toda convicção, mas se eu não me engano a API redis que você esta usando não tem suporte para await, portanto teria que fazer na mão, usando [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), assim:

```
function getCache(key)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cache.get(key, (err, value) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve("" + value);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

E usar `await`, assim:

```
app.post("/calculofatorial", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.body.s1;
    let valueId = await getCache(`fatorial:${id}`);

...
```

Comment: caralho... vou chorar.... porra... amigo... estou muito feliz... passei 12horas tentando entender isso... cara... conseguimos!!!!! obrigado... meu deus... estou chorando de felicidade.... putz.z...

Comment: deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: @Glarcan se resolveu o seu problema por favor marque a resposta como correta. Grato!